# With VBA, find the version of the MySQL ODBC driver installed in Windows

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, odbc, connection-string

**Using Visual Basic for Applications**, how can I find out which version of the MySQL ODBC driver is installed in Windows on a user's machine?

I have a Microsoft Access application that uses the MySQL ODBC driver to make a connection.  The connection string looks like this:

```
ODBC;DATABASE=mydatabase;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
    OPTION=3;PWD=password;PORT=3306;SERVER=server-db;UID=db-user;
```

This was working find until the IT manager installed version 5.1 of the MySQL ODBC driver on a user's PC, which broke my connection string.

If I knew the version of the driver installed on the user's Windows XP installation, I could insert that into the connection string at run-time.  **How can I find out which version of the MySQL ODBC driver is installed in Windows on a user's machine using VBA?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find it in the registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
    ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
    ODBC Drivers\MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver


 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
    ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
    ODBC Drivers\MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
```

Using the info found [here](http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html), you can get at it using the below code (I tested it in Access 97)

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()    
    If RegKeyExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
                                 ODBC Drivers\MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver") Then
        MsgBox "3.51"
    ElseIf RegKeyExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
                                 ODBC Drivers\MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver") Then
        MsgBox "5.1"
    Else
        MsgBox "None"
    End If
End Sub


'returns True if the registry key i_RegKey was found
'and False if not
Function RegKeyExists(i_RegKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim myWS As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'access Windows scripting
    Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'try to read the registry key
    myWS.RegRead i_RegKey
    'key was found
    RegKeyExists = True
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
  'key was not found
  RegKeyExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: How can I use VBA to look at the registry at the location you specified?

Comment: You will find script here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020181/find-version-of-access/2020919#2020919 for checking the registry that will work in Access.

Comment: That script uses VB.NET, which doesn't always translate to VBA.  How will it work?

Comment: Just a thought but the function checks the key exists, not the value of the key, I don't know if the key is uninstalled with the driver. so you may with to check the value of the key too. there is a function for that in the link in my answer.

Comment: @Ben McCormick 'That script' does not use VB.Net, it uses VBScript, and works fine in Access. Or at least it did when I put it together :)

Comment: The script is not using VBScript, but VBA, since it will be run within Access. As written, it would require substantial editing to run as a VBScript.

Comment: @DW Fenton, if you are referring to my comment, the script I refer to is in the link I posted as a comment, at that time the post above did not have any code at all. The script in the link is VBScript, I tested in both Access and VBScript when I was putting it together.

Comment: OK -- I missed tracing things back. Probably not a good idea to use something as ambiguous as "that script" in a comment, don't you think?

Comment: Might be worth adding a check for 64bit systems as RegKey path differs HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few possible ideas:

1 You may be able to check the registry and look for specific keys, like this for example: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver]

2.You could check their c:\windows\system32 folder for the myodbc.dll, and then check the version information.  Here's a link on how to check the version:
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_file_version_info.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid handling versions on a case by case basis you can iterate through the key values, eg..

This function is designed to enumerate through the regkeys for ODBC drivers and just check for the existance of mysql somewhere, if not it will warn the user then take them to the download page, and remind them to get the right version for their architecture (32/64)

```
Public Function CheckMySQL()

    Dim arrEntryNames()
    Dim arrValueTypes()
    Dim rPath As String
    rPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"

    Call EnumerateRegEntries(rPath, arrEntryNames, arrValueTypes)

    If Not IsEmpty(arrEntryNames) Then
        For Each strAsk In arrEntryNames
            If (InStr(strAsk, "MySQL")) Then
                strFound = strFound & strAsk & ", "
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (Len(strFound) = 0) Then
        #If Win64 Then
            MsgBox "You need MySQL Driver *64 bit* - Press OK to get it!"
        #Else
            MsgBox "You need MySQL Driver *32 bit* - Press OK to get it!"
        #End If

        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://goo.gl/vbm6g", NewWindow:=True

        CheckMySQL = False
    Else
        CheckMySQL = True
    End If

End Function
```

And you'll need this to enumerate the reg keys (for more on this see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176771.aspx):

```
Public Sub EnumerateRegEntries(strKeyPath, arrEntryNames, arrValueTypes)
    Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000&
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001&
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002&
    Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003&
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005&

    Dim objReg As Object
    Dim strComputer As String

    strComputer = "."
    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    objReg.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrEntryNames, arrValueTypes


End Sub
```

Comment: Note: `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` is for excel. `FollowHyperlink` works fine in Access.
Tip: Update the code to return the found correct string, eg:
`If (InStr(strAsk, "MySQL") > 0 And InStr(strAsk, "Unicode") > 0) Then
                strFound = strAsk
                modLog.Log LOGNAME, "Found matching MySQL Driver: " & strFound, LOG_INFO
            End If`
and
`Else
        CheckMySQL= strFound
End If
`