# Check if SQL Server Client Is Installed

Tags: sql-server, registry

How can one check to see if the SQL Server Client driver is installed? And is it also possible to determine the version?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to->Run->cmd->type *regedit.exe* and you see the registry under the ODBC folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
    ODBC Drivers\SQL Server
```

[image]

I also find [a complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050443/with-vba-find-the-version-of-the-the-mysql-odbc-driver-installed-in-windows) about this issue, (based on MySQL, but basically is the same thing).

Edit later: according to your comment you have installed the 2005 version of SQL Server:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
Microsoft SQL Native Client\CurrentVersion
```

Anyway I also show you how you can see the 2008 version to see the differences between the two versions.

**For SQL Server 2008/R2:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
```

**For SQL Server 2012:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: I think you might be on the right track here but I'm not seeing anything listed under ODBC Drivers.

Comment: I am seeing this in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mcirosft\Microsoft SQQL Native Client\CurrentVersion

Comment: If you see this and not \SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion., you have the 2005 version., I update my answer.

Comment: I think I probably have both installed. I didn't look far enough to both of them.

Comment: For SQL Server 2012

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion

Comment: This link seems to have the registry locations for all versions. Hopefully, it stays updated; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185

Answer (score 9):

This can be found by running `odbcad32.exe`.

From the [Microsoft Support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185):

> To determine the version of SQL Server Native Client, use one of the following methods:
>
> Method 1: On the system where you want to find the version of Native Client, start the ODBC Administrator (`odbcad32.exe`), and then check the Version column under the Drivers tab.

On 64-bit systems, also check `odbcad64.exe`.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no command line interface which means you can't do this automatically

Answer (score 2):

It can be gotten through `req query`

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft /f Native*Client /k
```

result

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0
End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

then you can get exact number by parsing, for example, in python

```
import os
import re
os.system("reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft /f Native*Client /k > C:\\reg.out")
out=open("C:\\reg.out").read()
ver=re.search("Native Client (\d+)").group(1)
print(ver)
```

And you get `ver=11`
There is also faster way

```
code = os.system("reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft /f Native*Client*11 /k > null")
code == 0 # means there is client of version 11
code == 1 # means there is no such client
```