# SQL server version query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, version

How to check whether we have installed sql server full version or client version ?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499643/check-if-sql-server-client-is-installed). I hope you'll get what you want to check

Comment: how to identify the difference between the full version and client version

Comment: What is "client version"?? You mean client tools only?

Comment: select @@version ;    sys.dm_exec_sessions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select @@version`

Or to get more data:

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')AS Product_version, 
        SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel')AS Product_level,
        SERVERPROPERTY('edition')AS Edition
```

Comment: Is enterprise edition is the full version of sql server and what will be the editon for client version

Comment: client version mean's,, i know only(enterprise ,express ,standard ,developer)

Answer (score 0):

To get some more details like Edition, Service Pack.

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')as 'Host Name', 
        SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') as 'Instance Name' , 
        SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') as 'Cluster' , 
    SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') as 'Edition',
        SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as 'version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('Productlevel') as 'Service Pack',   
        SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType') as 'LicenseType' ,
        SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses') as 'NumLicenses'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this query which it gonna return data like this: 
**SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition (64-bit) 13.0.5237.0 SP2**

```
DECLARE 
    @productver VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS VARCHAR(50)))
DECLARE 
    @version VARCHAR(30)= CAST(LEFT(@productver, CHARINDEX('.', @productver)-1) AS INT)
SELECT 
    'SQL Server '+CASE @version
                      WHEN 9
                          THEN '2005'
                      WHEN 10
                          THEN '2008'
                      WHEN 11
                          THEN '2012'
                      WHEN 12
                          THEN '2014'
                      WHEN 13
                          THEN '2016'
                      WHEN 14
                          THEN '2017'
                              ELSE 'Unknow Version'
                    END + ' ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('edition') AS VARCHAR(50))          AS SQLServerEdition,
    @productver                                                                         AS ProductVersion, 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel')                                                      AS ServicePack
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux Terminal:
`$ sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa`

Note: Here `sa` is the `username`, change it if your `username` is different.

Provide your `password` then enter your sql server.
Write:
`1> select @@VERSION`
`2> GO`

[image: The sql server version output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this to know **your SQL Server Version**:

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```