# How to query MySQL ODBC version in LabVIEW

Tags: mysql, labview

I'm communicating with a database via the MySQL ODBC driver.  I must deploy the software on different computers.

On the development computer I have MySQL ODBC 5.3 and on the target computer, I have MySQL ODBC 8.0.

[image]

Is there a simple way to determine the MySQL ODBC driver version so that I can modify the connection string if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050443/24447) suggest that the data you need can be read from the Windows registry, e.g.:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
    ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
    ODBC Drivers\MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver
```

Assuming that's true, you should be able to query the value using the [Windows Registry Access VIs](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/windows_registry_access_vi/).