# Check if Access 2010 installed gives exeption

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I'm trying to check if Access 2010 installed with C#, I tried to use [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438061/9250176).

He use there `subString` instead of `Substring` also with `indexOf` instead of `IndexOf`.

So in my code i done it with `Substring`and `IndexOf`, but when I run it gives `FormatException`, here is my code:

```
RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Access.Application\CurVer" , false);

if (rootKey == null)
{     
    MessageBox.Show("Access 2010 not installed on this machine");
}

String value = rootKey.GetValue("").ToString();
int verNum = 0;
try
{
    verNum = int.Parse(value.Substring(value.IndexOf("Access.Application.")));
} catch (FormatException fe)
{
    MessageBox.Show(fe.ToString());
}

if (value.StartsWith("Access.Application.") && verNum >= 12)
{       
    MessageBox.Show("Access 2010 already installed on this machine");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to fully debug this - what does _"value"_ equal, what does _"value.IndexOf("Access.Application.")"_ return, what is the result of _"value.Substring(...)"_

Comment: on debugger value equals `Access.Application.15`

Comment: Have you checked the other results as I suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way on earth what you have is going to work (just saying)

You have obviously obtained this code from here or some derivative [Check if MS Access 2010 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438002/check-if-ms-access-2010-is-installed)... And its horribly wrong

**Firstly**

[string.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified
>   string in this instance

Meaning its going to return 0 if it finds `"Access.Application."`

**Secondly**

[String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

Which means, given 0 will return `"Access.Application."` and that is not an `int`

**Lastly**

[Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Throws an exception if its not an `int`

---

Im not sure of the correct way to find the access version number or how to detect if access is installed. However, **if** the version number truly lives behind `"Access.Application."` you'd want to use [String.LastIndexOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) passing in `.`

At the very least use [int.TryParse](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure it doesnt throw an exception

**Example**

```
var somekey = "Access.Application.2099";
var lastIndex = somekey.LastIndexOf(".");

if (lastIndex > 0)
   Console.WriteLine("We have a chance");

var substr = somekey.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

Console.WriteLine(substr);

int verNum = 0;

if (int.TryParse(substr, out verNum))
{
   Console.WriteLine("found a version maybe : " + verNum);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No cigar");
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8wK8j)